# How to extract the bitstream from H.264 video?

Tags: matlab, video, ffmpeg, h.264

I have a H.264 video and I want to extract the bitstream from it. In other words, I need to know the stream after encoding a video via H.264 standard. I am going to use the extracted stream in Matlab. How can I do this (extract the bitstream)? Is it possible to use ffmpeg?if so what is the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c copy -f h264 stream.264
```

Depending on what MATLAB expects, you may need to add a bitstream filter

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c copy -f h264 -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb stream.264
```

Comment: what does the filter do? how to convert the stream to the video?

Comment: Annex B streams have a start code prefixed before each NALU. Regular AVCC streams don't.